# How to use key events to translate object in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, keyboard-events, glm-math

I am trying to have key presses move the object. I have a model view projection matrix that I am applying to my object in my vertex shader. However, I don't understand how I am meant to apply a transformation when pressing a key. I thought that I would have to update the MVP matrix such that mvp = mvp * transMatrix. However, it changes nothing. My keyboard function looks like this:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) { 
    case 'd':
        mvp = mvp * r;
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `mvp` is a model view projection matrix and `r` is a translation matrix, both of which are globally defined. `mvp` is the matrix that I am sending to my vertex shader with the following code:

```
GLint uniTrans = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "trans");
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));
```

However, this code doesn't actually work. The object still appears, but pressing the 'd' key does nothing. Why is this? How am I meant to update the transformation matrix that I send to the vertex shader? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to translate an object in view space, then you've to `mvp = projection * view * r * model;`

Comment: Do you re-set `mvp` before rendering the cube, by any chance?

Comment: By the way, there is no way that "you're meant to." That's your job. OpenGL cares what matrix you give it, not how you got that matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. You must call glutPostRedisplay after change mvp. This instruction forces to call display function and redraw the scene, otherwise it is only called if you minimize and restore the window.
2. You have registered the keyboard function before glutCreateWindow. So the functions is not registered because you haven't created the OpenGL Window.